# Unable to extract a substring from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Pandas and Python . My data frame looks like this . I am trying to extract apple, watermelon etc. from the given rows . Kindly suggest

```py
.\dnn\train\apple\Image_1.jpg
1   ..\dnn\train\apple\Image_10.jpg
2   ..\dnn\train\apple\Image_100.jpg
3   ..\dnn\train\apple\Image_11.jpg
4   ..\dnn\train\apple\Image_13.jpg

3273    ..\dnn\train\watermelon\Image_95.jpg
3274    ..\dnn\train\watermelon\Image_96.jpg
3275    ..\dnn\train\watermelon\Image_97.jpg
3276    ..\dnn\train\watermelon\Image_98.jpg
3277    ..\dnn\train\watermelon\Image_99.jpg
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] and include software version numbers. End of Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row=str(row).split("\\")`.

It worked after converting the entire dataframe to `String`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, this would create a new column with the extracted words

```
df[‘watermelon_apple’] = df[‘image_path’].str.split(‘\’).str[-2]
```

This would split the string by ‘\’ and return the last second element and make a new column holding that value

Comment: Hello Thank you for your reply it does not work . I tried this way data['newdf']= df['col1'].str.split('\\')[-2] and it is giving me error  ValueError: -2 is not in range.